# How do I get the HTML from a decompiled WebForms project (.aspx files)

Tags: c#, html, webforms, decompiling

I was tasked with de-compiling an old WebForms project.
I have used both .NET Reflector and ILSpy to open the .dll's and I can clearly see the methods and C# code in there but I can't seem to be able to find the html anywhere in there.
The reason for de-compiling is to extract a piece of functionality that's in there, but I cannot do anything with the C# code if I am missing a huge HTML front end for the page.
Anyone?

Comment: A compiled WebForms project has DLLs, but also aspx files, that contain the "UI" part of the project. Also, could be .js, .css, images, etc. Without these files, you wont be able to recreate the full functionality. I suppose you are decompiling from a production site. Ask the people that gave you the dlls for the full site, not only the bin folder.

Comment: Correct. I am decompiling from a production site, and I have the whole site, just can't seem to find the html anywhere in there. I have the .js files and the aspx "UI" code but still without the HTML both are useless.

Comment: If it is a precompiled project, all the .aspx and .ascx files will be empty, and you will have to find the compiled code to build the HTML inside the dlls. You may have a bunch of dlls with more or less random names (App_Web_xxxxxx) or a single big dll. Using ILSpy, if you have located the server side code, you cand right-click the method and use the "Analyze" option. Look for "ASP.xxxx" elemnts in the "Used By" section of the analysis. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and do that.

Comment: If you need HTML only then you can find all HTML code in .ASPX file. and why you don't have the source of project is it lost or they dont have it?

Comment: Yeah couldn't see it in the aspx file anywhere. The source code was lost by an outsourced team.